# How to click on a context menu- popup menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, contextmenu

I need to do the following:

1) Right click on a element

2) Context menu is displayed

3) On moving
       to a specific menu (move_to_element) in context menu - pops up
       another menu say MenuX

4) Need to click on MenuX

I am able to do steps 1 to 3 but not 4.
When I checked `is_displayed` for MenuX it returns `False`

When I try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[5]/span[2]")`
it works (I do not want to hardcode).
But not with id of menu.

Also tried  but no luck
`actions = ActionChains(driver)`
`actions.move_to_element(menu)`
`actions.click(hidden_submenu)`
`actions.perform()`

I also tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#contextMenu_Div #menuX")` and it didn't work.
MenuX is not link but a span element.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below code in order to click on the sub menu item after right clicking:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement("Find the element on which right click needs to be performed"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("menulink"));
actions.moveToElement(mainMenu);

WebElement menuX = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("subLinklocator"));
actions.moveToElement(menuX);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Karthik for the suggestion but it didnt help.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this..

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.contextClick(mainelement);
actions.moveToElement(menuelement);
actions.perform();

//at this point ur MenuX shd be visisble.

driver.findElement("locator for ur MenuX").click();
```